# NextAuth.js for authentication with Okta

Tags: reactjs, next.js, okta

i want the 2 skin shown in the pictures to be removed and to navigate directly to the user and password skin for authentication. Could any one help me out on how to implement it?

[This is the 1st skin(the login page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wce9f.png)
[This is the 2nd skin which am trying to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdcGy.png)

[This is the page i want to navigate to from the 1st login skin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX4TF.png)

Comment: This has been closed by someone who doesn't understand the question so I can't answer it.

The answer is you can specify the provider ID when calling `signIn()` - e.g.  `signIn('okta')`